# Gitlab: Trigger multiple jobs from 1 other job

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a job that users use as a template by using `extend` keyword

I wish to maintain backwards compatibility and want to add a scanner to this job. Some users might extend my template multiple times when they build multiple images in their pipeline.

I was thinking on replacing the job (using the same name) and triggering 2 jobs (one for building the image and one for scanning). The pipeline would look like this

```
. (stages)
├── A
│   ├── build
│   └── scan (depends on build)
├── B
└── C
```

But i can't use the `trigger` keyword to do this. I am only allowed to trigger one job?

How can I achieve my end goal:

- maintain the same name on the template
- Allow the user to build and scan multiple images by referencing only 1 template

Edit 1:

The users use the template as an extend, as such:

```yaml
include: 
- project : 'ci-tools/container-image-ci-templates'
  file : 'kaniko-image.gitlab-ci.yml'
  ref: master

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_container:
  rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  stage: build
  extends: .build_kaniko
  variables:
    REGISTRY_IMAGE_PATH : "registry.foo.bar/MYPROJECT/MYIMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
    CONTEXT_DIR: "dockerfiles_folder"
    DOCKER_FILE_NAME: "Dockerfile_ubuntu"  

deploy_container:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  stage: deploy
  extends: .build_kaniko
  variables:
    PUSH_IMAGE: "true"
    REGISTRY_IMAGE_PATH : "registry.foo.bar/MYPROJECT/MYIMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
    CONTEXT_DIR: "dockerfiles_folder"
    DOCKER_FILE_NAME: "Dockerfile_ubuntu"
```

So from here, I want to create a new pipeline from this different pipelines (that are triggered in different situations [branch/tag]). But Some users also include multi-image build by specifying different DOCKERFILE_NAME. ex:

```yaml
...
build_container_container1:
  rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  stage: build
  extends: .build_kaniko
  variables:
    REGISTRY_IMAGE_PATH : "registry.foo.bar/MYPROJECT/MYIMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
    CONTEXT_DIR: "dockerfiles_folder"
    DOCKER_FILE_NAME: "Dockerfile_ubuntu_1"  

build_container_container2:
  rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  stage: build
  extends: .build_kaniko
  variables:
    REGISTRY_IMAGE_PATH : "registry.foo.bar/MYPROJECT/MYIMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
    CONTEXT_DIR: "dockerfiles_folder"
    DOCKER_FILE_NAME: "Dockerfile_fedora" 
...
```

Comment: Can you give an example `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that shows how users use the current job you've written? When you say you want users to "build and scan multiple images by referencing only 1 template" do you mean "template" as in an `include:`d configuration or as in `extends:` or something else?

Comment: Added the `Edit 1` with an example of the usage of the template